Is it common to install idol of Shri Vishnu atop of Yoni like in this picture? What does it signify in tradition?
This is the picture of our clan god where idol of shri vishnu is installed on a yoni (shakti). What does this arrangement signify in tradition?

I don't see Sanku and Chakra but I see Urdhva Pundra (ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र) in yellow color on the forehead!

Where is this temple?

It isn't a yoni. It is a snanapitha or an altar specifically designed for conducting abhisheka. In these type of altars, ablution waters are channeled down to the drain, instead of freely flowing down at the front of the altar.

@Marmayogi Its in Dapoli near Ratnagiri, Maharashtra.

@অনু Okay. I had one more question. Can you tell me more about the temple Like whether Its puranic, Agamic, Tantric? Its type of architecture etc. The temple is Shri Keshavraj, Asud Baug, Ratnagiri, Maharashtra
